# Extracting key and array value from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My data looks like this:

```
const sleepStages = [
  {deep: Array(40)},
  {light: Array(40)},
  {rem: Array(40)},
  {awake: Array(40)},
]
```

I'm using the key and values separately and am using TypeScript.

```
sleepStages.flatMap((sleepStage) => {
  const stageName = Object.keys(sleepStage)[0];
  const stageValues = Object.values(sleepStage)[0];
  console.log(stageName, stageValues);
});
```

Does this approach make sense? Whenever I type `[0]` it smells.

Comment: I can speculate that this is not the best way to store your data. However you haven't provided enough code for me to evolve this speculation into anything more. Right now I can think of plenty of different, potentially better or worse, solutions. As such I'm voting to close this as missing context. Whilst answerable, the answers you'll get will be sub-par.

Comment: This seems like such a harsh criticism and result. What if the data is from an external API? That, and the answer by @CertainPerformance is specifically helpful along with a useful criticism of the data. ‍♂️

Comment: If your data is coming from an API then your question is lacking a description at best, deceptive at worst. Either way it's off-topic. Closing a question that is off-topic is not harsh.

Comment: Was just trying to keep things succinct. I'll do better next time. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ok. If you avoid being succinct then you should avoid this 'hostility' in the future.

Comment: Unlike Stack Overflow, being overly succinct is actually a problem here. If you keep that in mind for next time, I'm sure it will all be fine. When in doubt, see our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: I'm guessing you meant "not actually a problem here". Thanks for the feedback Mast. I'll definitely provide more context in my next question.

Comment: @GollyJer No, they wrote what they meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more concise approach would be to use `Object.entries` to get the 0th key and value at once:

```
const [stageName, stageValues] = Object.entries(sleepStage)[0];
```

Yes, the `[0]` looks weird, but unless you know the keys and/or in advance, you *have* to use a method which iterates over them, and then you need to extract the first item. In Javascript, there's no good way of avoiding the `[0]` - there's nothing like `Object.prototype.getFirstEntry`.

You could nest the destructuring on the left side, but that looks much less readable IMO:

```
const [[stageName, stageValues]] = Object.entries(sleepStage);
```

Ideally, in this sort of situation, you would fix the input data so that the keys are predictable and static:

```
const sleepStages = [
  { name: 'deep', values: Array(40) },
  { name: 'light', values: Array(40) },
  { name: 'rem', values: Array(40) },
  { name: 'awake', values: Array(40) },
]
```

Then, in the loop, you could do:

```
const { name, values } = sleepStage;
```

Comment: +1 for the proposed structure improvement. Whenever there is a need to get an index like `[0]` on object keys or value, there is a better way of structuring the data, because object keys are by nature not guaranteed to be ordered. It also allows one of my favorite destructuring construct in modern javascript: `for (const { name, values } of sleepStages) {}`, where `sleepStages: { name: string, values: any[] }[]`

Comment: Object property order *is* guaranteed, in all but pathological cases, [as of ES2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444453), and has been effectively implemented in all implementations for years. Still, yeah, it's a code smell to rely on it.

Comment: wow, good to know, thanks

Comment: Thank you. This was super helpful. `.entries` wasn't on my radar until now. I'm using it for now and have asked our data team to update structure of the source data. 